# mysql - Calculate Percentage from two different table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, and i want to get the percentage value and update the percentage to the table. Suppose we have two table like this,

**Table 1**

```
   date     open   high   low   close   stock_id
2013-01-02   10     20     5     15        1
2013-01-02   150    200   100    170       2
2013-01-03   15     30     10    20        1
```

**Table 2**

```
   date     p_high  p_low   percent   stock_id
2013-01-02   25     10       0.00        1
2013-01-02   210    120      0.00        2
2013-01-03   40     20       0.00        1
```

I want to calculate the percentage using this formula

```
(p_high - high) / high
```

Percentage for `stock_id = 1` in `date = 2013-01-02` will be like this.

```
(25 - 20) / 20 = 25.00
```

When i get the percentage, i want to update it to **Table 2** so it will be like this,

```
  date      p_high   p_low   percent   stock_id
2013-01-02    25      10      25.00       1
```

How can i do that in mysql?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you use stored procedure? in your example you have 2x stock=1?

Comment: add a primary key and foreign key that would be easier to join

Comment: Did someone question helped you (mark it as accepted if so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DDL**

```
create table table1(
    created_dt date,
    open decimal(5,2),
    high decimal(5,2),
    low decimal(5,2),
    close decimal(5,2),
    stock_id integer
);

create table table2(
    created_dt date,
    p_high decimal(5,2),
    p_low decimal(5,2),
    percent decimal(5,2),
    stock_id integer
);
```

**DML**

```
insert into table1 values ('2013-01-02',10,20,5,15,1);
insert into table1 values ('2013-01-02',150,200,100,170,2);
insert into table1 values ('2013-01-03',15,30,10,20,1);

insert into table2 values('2013-01-02',25,10,0.00,1);
insert into table2 values('2013-01-02',210,120,0.00,2);
insert into table2 values('2013-01-02',40,20,0.00,1);

update table2
join table1
on table1.created_dt = table2.created_dt and table1.stock_id = table2.stock_id
set percent = ((p_high - high)/high);
```

**Working Example** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21d02/1/0

Comment: Your code is great. It is working like what i need. Btw, sorry everyone for the long reply. i've been busy for a while. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61c460/2

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.stock_id = t1.stock_id AND t1.date = t2.date 
SET 
    t2.percent = (t2.p_high - t1.high) / t1.high;
```

Sqlfiddle will not allow updates but if you get the query and run in mysql will work.

Is possible to have multiple entries for same stock and date?